# CSS selector incorrect format

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I have tried everything but I keep getting an error that it is wrong
if anyone could help.

```
<td class="CLS 1989 ptable-param">
                                                            
<span id="part-status" title="">
            Active
        </span>

                                                </td>
```

```
        if p.css('td.CLS.1989.ptable-param span#part-status::text').get():
            status = p.css('td.CLS.1989.ptable-param span#part-status::text').get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and make sure `part-status` is available in page source

```
response.css('#part-status ::text').get()
```